# Starting application on RDS connection

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, rdp, terminal-server

I have the following servers:

Server 1 - Windows 2003: The original Domain Controller for AD, DNS Server

server 2 - WIndows 2012: The latest server, upgraded to a domain controller too

Now when I go to Active Directory users, right click properties on a user and set on environment tab to start a program after logon, it works just fine on the the terminal server connection to the Windows 2003 server. But it doesn't work on Windows 2012 terminal server at all, and I don't know why, I've certified myself that the path is functional and everything.

Anybody has any clues of whats going on?

Comment: It's not even clear what the heck you're describing.  What's a RE server and what's an ACD server?

Comment: Try and read again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Microsoft [forum post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/2b55ff33-3706-44e4-88a6-19c0b140cd25/option-to-start-the-following-program-on-connection-will-only-work-if-terminal-services-role-is?forum=winserverTS) suggests at at least in Server 2008 there was a bug impacting the functionality of this option.  A poster as recently as December 2012 indicated the problem was still present.  It's possible this hasn't been corrected in Server 2012 either.

Answer (score 0):

In order for that to work in Windows 2012 you have to publish the program as a Remote App, if I'm not mistaken.

I remember seeing something about it on a Pluralsight course but I can't seem to find more info now.